# Named outlet component loaded into the root component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular6, angular-router

I'm trying to implement sidenav with Auxiliary routes, but without a success.

This is simplified example of my router:

```
{
        path: 'admin',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ReportsPageComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':userID',
                component: ReportsUserPageComponent,
                resolve: {userID: UserIDResolver},
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'day-detail/:day',
                        outlet: 'sidenav',
                        component: DayDetailComponent,
                        resolve: {dayRange: DayRangeResolver},
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
```

The main-layout.component.html :

```
<div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<router-outlet name="sidenav"></router-outlet>
```

Then the navigation in the ReportsUserPageComponent

```
this.router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { sidenav: ['day-detail', new Date().toJSON()] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Which creates something like this

```
admin/9/(sidenav:day-detail/2018-06-22T13:28:11.737Z)
```

The problem is that it doesnt want to load the DayDetailComponent. I need this to be as a children of the ReportsUserPageComponent, because I don't want something like this `admin/(9//sidenav:day-detail/2018-06-20T22:00:00.000Z)` becuase once I go back, those brackets remain there ( `admin/(9)` ) for no apparent reason.

Comment: can you please create a https://stackblitz.com/ example of your problem?

Comment: please create a working example or post all relevant code. We can't reproduce your problem

Comment: I've realised that what I want isn't possible to approach. The only solution to this is to have path: 'day-detail/:day', in the same level as this path: ':userID'. But there comes this bug from Angular 6 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24656